# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a weather a react app in codesandbox for a school project. Everything looks okay on paper but I get the error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I'm doing a weather app type project. My API is correct from openweather. error points me to this:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const UseFetch = (initialUrl) => {
  // create state variables
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!url) return;
    setIsLoading(true);
    // clear old search
    setData(null);
    setError(null);

    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {

            // error handling for nonexistent data
            setIsLoading(false);
            if(data.cod >= 400) {
                setError(data.message);
                return;
            }
            setData(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setError(error);
        });
  }, [url]);

  return { data, error, isLoading, setUrl };
};

export default UseFetch;
```

error appears at setError(error) section. What am I doing wrong?

And this is where I call the error

```
import React from 'react';
import CitySelector from './components/CitySelector';
import './App.css';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import UseFetch from './hooks/UseFetch';
import {API_KEY, API_BASE_URL} from './apis/config'
import WeatherList from './components/WeatherList';

const App = () => {
  const {data, error, isLoading, setUrl} = UseFetch();

  const getContent = () => {
    if(error) return <h2>Error when fetching: {error}</h2>
    if(!data && isLoading) return <h2>LOADING...</h2>
    if(!data) return null;
    return <WeatherList weathers={data.list} />
  };

  return (
    <Container className="App">
      <CitySelector onSearch={(city) => setUrl(`${API_BASE_URL}/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&cnt=5&appid=${API_KEY}`)} />

      {/* conditionally render  */}
      {getContent()}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: i believe your issue is where you're rendering the api data can i see that by chance

Comment: Instead of doing `setError(error)` you could do `setError(JSON.strigify(error))`. That should fix the issue. However, as @Robert said you should change your rendering logic of the error instead. Rendering `error.message` instead of just `error` might help. But still, you should provide your render function's code for better understanding.

Comment: I added the code where I called the error @Kiran
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `error` that you are showing on this line below is an `Object` which is not a valid display type in JSX.

```js
if(error) return <h2>Error when fetching: {error}</h2>
```

What you can do:

1. Show a stringified error in the above line. i.e. by changing it too:

```js
if(error) return <h2>Error when fetching: {JSON.stringify(error)}</h2>
```

However, you will get unwanted texts & stack traces displayed in your app if you go with this approach.

2. Show `error.message` if it exists. Almost all the javascript/custom errors have the `message` property which contains the most relevant information for displaying what the error is. If this property doesn't contain a value, you can show your custom error message (like: 'Something went wrong').

```js
if(error) return <h2>Error when fetching: {error.message || 'Something went wrong'}</h2>
```

I would suggest option 2 over option 1.